# Métodos Get ApiRest

Tags: javascript, html, ajax, json

Estoy aprendiendo y experimentando, y necesito ayuda en este problema para mi..

No soy bueno en Js,

Estoy usando las variables **consuKey** y **consuSecr** para agregarlas en el **GET ajax**. donde esta el **consumer_key=** y **consumer_secret=**

¿Cómo podría hacerlo?

```
    var consuKey = "ck_xxxxxx";
    var consuSecr = "cs_xxxxxx";

    //LAST WEEK GET

    function callurl() {
    $.ajax({
    url: 'https://domain.com/wc-api/v2/reports/sales?filter[period]=last_week&consumer_key=&consumer_secret=',
    type: "GET",
    dataType: "json"
    })
    .done(function(data){
    JsonpCallback(data.orders)
    })
    .fail(function(data){
    console.log("no");
    })
    }
```

Comment: @eduardorq Gracias! por ayudarme a mejorar mi redacción! :), no soy nada bueno en eso... :(

Comment: De nada... @Juan David únicamente intento poner mi granito de arena :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Prueba a mandarlos a través del objeto `data`:

```
$.ajax({
    url: 'https://domain.com/wc-api/v2/reports/sales',
    data:{
        filter: {period: "last_week"},
        consumer_key: consuKey,
        consumer_secret: consuSecr
    },
    type: "GET",
    dataType: "json"
})...
```

Comment: tengo el siguiente error Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token [

Comment: Prueba a quitar los corchetes y hacerlo como lo actualicé.